# JSF 2: Prevent share managed bean between session users login

Tags: jsf-2

I have a trouble about using property in managed bean JSF 2.0.

1. display.xhtml

   ```
   <p:commandButton value="Show" actionListener="#{ABean.ajaxShow}" update="info" />
   <p:commandButton value="Hide" actionListener="#{ABean.ajaxHide}" update="info" />
      <p:outputPanel id="info">
       <p:fieldset rendered="#{ABean.show}">
          Info
       </p:fieldset>
   </p:outputPanel>
   ```
2. ABean.java

   @Named("ABean")

   public class ABean {
       private boolean show;

   ```
   public void ajaxShow() {
       show = true;
   }

   public void ajaxHide() {
       show = false;
   }

   //getter setter
   ```

   }

This project is setup spring security 3.1.2 and manage user system.

When there are 2 user login and open this page, user 1 click Show button, then 'Info' is displayed. So when user 2 go to this page, he'll see info displayed. If user 2 click Hide button, info is hide. Refresh this page which user 1 visit, info is hide.

That's strange. I need the page user 1 visit only change info state (show/hide) when user 1 click button, not cause by user 2 on user2's page.

I think it happens because 2 session of 2 user only use 1 managed bean instance. How can I do for this case? Please help me to resolve, thank you!

PS: I try to add @SessionScoped, @ViewScoped, @RequestScoped for ABean but nothing change.

Comment: To exclude the obvious, are the users also really using different browser sessions? So, when you tested this locally, are you also using two physically different browsers? E.g. one user in Firefox and other user in Chrome. Multiple tabs/windows of the same browser instance will namely share the same HTTP session.

Comment: Thanks for reply, BalusC.
I test with 2 browser for users (firefox, IE).

Comment: Additional Info: I also test with 2 computers in LAN. I run localhost on a computer, and test this scenario from 2 other computers

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this problem. But I don't understand why can't use BalusC 's solution (I think it 's right, but...)
I use

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;  
@Named
@Scope("request") // or use session,..
```

So, everything work successfully. If you know, please let me know why it works when I use Scope from springframework.context.annotation package. Thank you!

Comment: You were using the 3rd party Spring framework instead of the Java EE standard CDI framework! That explains everything. In future questions please explicitly mention that you're using Spring instead of standard Java EE APIs.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I remember your advice for my future questions. Thank you very much, BalusC.